# Differentiable convex function that is not continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

Does there exist a convex function that is differentiable over an **open** convex set but not continuously differentiable there?

Any differentiable function defined on an interval is continuously differentiable due to the [monotonicity](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Equigg/teach/courses/371/2005fall/lectures/continuousmonotone.pdf) and [Darboux property](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Darboux_property) of its derivative. Therefore, the function, if exists, has to reside in a $2$- or higher-dimensional space. In addition, it needs to be continuously differentiable along any straight line.

Any comments or criticism will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**: Indeed, there does not exist such a function. See [Corollary 25.5.1, *Convex Analysis*, Rockafellar 1970].

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911841/differentiability-and-convex-function/3912463#3912463

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the example over there cannot be extended to a differentiable convex function on an open set that contains (0,0). What do you think?